# Validation loss when using Dropout

Tags: validation, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to understand the effect of dropout on validation Mean Absolute Error (non-linear regression problem).

**Without dropout**

[image]

**With dropout of 0.05**

[image]

**With dropout of 0.075**
[image]

Without any dropouts the validation loss is more than training loss as shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJPK9.png). My understanding is that the validation loss should only be slightly more than the training loss for a good fit.

Carefully, I increased the dropout so that validation loss is close to the training loss as seen in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoNdJ.png). The dropout is only applied during training and not during validation, hence the validation loss is lower than the training loss.

Finally the dropout was increased further and the validation loss again became more than the training loss in [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69o22.png).

Which amongst these three should be called as a good fit?

Following the response of Marcin Możejko, I predicted against three tests as shown in [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OImWV.png). The 'Y' axis shows RMS error instead of MAE. The model 'without dropout' gave the best result.

[image]

Comment: are you also using keras' provided validation function?

Comment: Yes, 80% for training and 20% for validation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well - this a really good question. In my opinion - the lowest validation score (confirmed on a separate *test set*) is the best fit. Remember that in the end - the performance of your model on a totally new data is the most crucial thing and the fact that it performed even better on a training set is not so important.

Moreover - I think that your model might generaly underfit - and you could try extend it to e.g. have more layers or neurons and prune it a little bit using `dropout` in order to prevent example memoization.

If my hypothesis turned out to be false - remember - that it still might be possible that there are certain data patterns present only on validation set (this relatively often in case of medium size datasets) what makes the divergence of train and test loss. Moreover - I think that even though that your losses values saturated in case without dropout there is still a room for improvement by simple increase in number of epochs as there seems to be a trend for losses to be smaller.

Another technique I recommend you to try is reducing learning rate on plateau (using example [this](https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau) callback) as your model seems to need refinement with lower value learning rate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the results of the 'test' in the OP.

Comment: Why do you think there is under-fitting going on? I guess this in reference to the model without dropout. Underfitting is when training and validation loss are similar, but have high error.

Not sure what you mean by 'it still might be possible that there are certain data patterns present only on validation set  what makes the divergence of train and test loss.' Are you suggesting that in my case the cross-validation error is less trust-worthy than test error.

Comment: What I meant is that sometimes your error comes from a simple split bias caused by the underrepresentation of some kind of data points in the training set. By underfit I meant that given bigger model capacity - it could actually capture more subtleties thanks to it - both losses should decrease.

Comment: Was my answer incorrect? If not - I'd appreciate an upvote and accepting it :)

Comment: I have to ask this again as well: which part of the curves you see made you think underfitting is going on? As to my knowledge you need to know the data, better metrics and maybe comparable datasets to judge this.