# How to confirm convergence of LSTM network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using LSTM for time-series prediction using Keras. I am using 3 LSTM layers with dropout=0.3, hence my training loss is higher than validation loss. To monitor convergence, I using plotting training loss and validation loss together. Results looks like the following.

[image]

After researching about the topic, I have seen multiple answers for example ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393438/validation-loss-when-using-dropout)[[2]](https://plot.ly/~jinjiren/41.embed) but I have found several contradictory arguments on various different places on the internet, which makes me a little confused. I am listing some of them below :

1) **Article presented by Jason Brownlee** suggests that validation and train data should meet for the convergence and if they don't, I might be **under-fitting** the data.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/diagnose-overfitting-underfitting-lstm-models/

https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/
 [image]

2) However, following answer on here suggest that **my model is just converged** :

[How do we analyse a loss vs epochs graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52145992/how-do-we-analyse-a-loss-vs-epochs-graph)

[image]

Hence, I am just bit confused about the whole concept in general. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convergence implies you have something to converge *to*. For a learning system to converge, you would need to know the right model beforehand. Then you would train your model until it was the same as the right model. At that point you could say the model converged! ... but the whole point of machine learning is that we don't know the right model to begin with.

So when do you stop training? In practice, you stop when the model works well enough to do what you want it to do. This might be when validation error drops below a certain threshold. It might just be when you can't afford any more computing power. It's really up to you.